# Reduce latency when rebuilding/updating Google Cloud Composer?

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am working with Google Cloud Composer, and whenever I change an environment variable or or any setting in airflow, it will trigger a rebuild of the airflow environment.

I was thinking there may be a way to resolve package dependencies (ie. upload python packages) to cut back on the rebuild latency.

I ask because the rebuild can take anywhere from 2-15 mins.

Has anyone had any luck with reducing this build time (with or without increasing costs)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment updates can generally take between 5-30 minutes in Cloud Composer and it works as intended at this moment. Please check this public [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/145625158) for more insight. You can click on `+1` to make it more visible to the Cloud Composer engineering team.

Please note, that the Composer needs to take care of a lot of resources, i.e. deploys Airflow within the Google Kubernetes Engine and App Engine, which forces rebuilding images of the container, updating the Airflow Webserver and so on.
I suggest you to take a look in the following Cloud Composer architecture [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/overview#architecture), where you can find all the components that needs to be updated with each change.

You can check if any of your PODs are in `Evicted` state, which means that your node is on low resource, so you should consider using higher resource machine instead of the standard one `n1-standard-2`.

I hope you find the above pieces of information useful.